# Need help with Columbia Lauderdale electric mountain bike

Tags: repair, electric-bike

I was recently riding my bicycle, and hit a speed bump when it turned off under me.

I checked out the bike and in the front motorhub there was a silver wire coming out of the bolt part. It looks sort of bent and when I looked at the wire it looks like it's kind of clipped not all the way off but I can probably solder it together without opening the whole hub.

Is there a special need for the silver spring that comes out of that bolt in the front hub?   Or could I just put it back in there without it turning off my bike.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE.  I found your question difficult to follow.  The lack of periods makes your question into one very long sentence and we don’t want to make assumptions of what you are trying to articulate and are actually asking.  Please edit your question so that we don’t have to make guesses as to the specific question you need answered.

Comment: I can take pictures of it when I pick it back up from work. I cannot ride it right now

Comment: From the description "Silver Spring" it could be wiring that is staked together, or it could be a reaction arm against torque.   Please do take some clear photos and add them with [edit]